# Does Nodes js AWS sdk automatically handles rate limiting and reties or do I need to attempt retry after parsing response

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

Do I need to handle this like :

```
ses.sendEmail( //body and other options
}, function (err, data) {
   if (err)
    //parse error and attmept to retry
});
```

Or will it be done just by handling it like :

```
var ses = new aws.SES({apiVersion: apiVersion,maxRetries: 10});
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK aws sdk does not handle rate limiting. use this  [rate limiting](https://github.com/jhurliman/node-rate-limiter) 
 module to wrap your ses.send like this,

```
var RateLimiter = require('limiter').RateLimiter;
// Allow 50 requests per second. Also understands
// 'second', 'minute', 'day', or a number of milliseconds
var limiter = new RateLimiter(50, 'second');

//huge number of requests
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
//Throttle requests
  limiter.removeTokens(1, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err
    // err will only be set if we request more than the maximum number of
    // requests we set in the constructor
    // remainingRequests tells us how many additional requests could be sent
    // right this moment
    ses.sendEmail({
      //body and other options
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) throw err
      //parse error and attempt to retry

    })

  });
}
```